# $\textbf{Q}$ fails to prove some correct $\forall$-rudimentary sentence

Tags: functions, logic, computability

> Show that the existence of a semirecursive set that is not recursive
>   implies that any consistent, axiomatizable extension of **Q** fails to
>   prove some correct $\forall$-rudimentary sentence.

I have the following facts:

1. Every recursive function is representable in **Q** (and by an $\exists$-rudimentary formula).
2. Every recursive relation is definable in **Q** (and by an $\exists$-rudimentary formula).

If $T$ is a consistent, axiomatizable theory containing **Q**:

1. Every set semi-definable in $T$ is semirecursive.
2. Every set definable in $T$ is recursive.
3. Every total function representable in $T$ is recursive.

Are there any examples of semirecursive sets where this structure holds? Or must their existence be proven mathematically?

Comment: Could you state the definition of a $\forall$_rudimentary sentence?

Comment: @CarlMummert A rudimentary formula is one built from atomic formulas using only negation, conjucnction, disjunction and bounded quantificiations $\forall x < t$ and $\exists x < t$, where $t$ is any term of the language. By $\exists$-rudimentary, it just means a formula of the form $\exists x F$ where $F$ is rudimentary, and the same for $\forall$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly many examples of sets of natural numbers that are semirecursive but not recursive.

One famous example begins with an enumeration $f_i$ of all the partial recursive functions. Let $A = \{ j : \text{for some $n$, } f_j(n) = 0\}$. That set is easily shown to be semirecursive, but a diagonalization argument shows that it is not recursive.

Another example is related to the halting problem: $B = \{ j : f_j(0) \text{ is defined} \}$. A similar diagonalization argument shows that this set is not recursive, but it is easily shown to be semirecursive.

The phenomenon of sets that are semirecursive but not recursive spreads throughout all of mathematical logic.

For example, the set of (codes of) formulas of the language of Peano Arithmetic that are provable in Peano Arithmetic. This set is semirecursive (search all proofs for a proof of a particular theorem) but, by the incompleteness theorems, it cannot be recursive.

Similarly, we can take the set of (codes of) first order sentences, in a language with one binary function symbol, that are logically valid. This set is semirecursive but not recursive. This is a famous theorem of Trahktenbot about undecidable theories. Many other undecidable theories are known.

For one more example, the set of (codes of) multivariate polynomials over the integers that have at least one root is semidecidable but not decidable - this is the resolution of Hilbert's 10th problem due to Matiyasevich, Davis, Putnam, and Robinson.

---

Here is the rest of the idea behind the problem. Let $A$ be a semirecursive set that is not recursive.

1. $A$ is definable by a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula $h$, i.e. a $\Sigma$-rudimentary formula. So we have that, for all $k$, $h(k) \leftrightarrow k \in A$. The complement of $h$ is a $\Pi^0_1$ formula, i.e., a $\forall$-rudimentary formula.
2. A particular property of $Q$  and stronger theories is that $Q$ is proves every true (i.e. correct) $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence. In particular, for each $k$ such that $k \in A$, we have that $Q$ proves $h(k)$.
3. Also, because the axioms of $Q$ are all true (i.e. correct), we have that for each $k$, if $Q$ proves $h(k)$ then $k \in A$, and if $Q$ proves $\lnot h(k)$ then $k \not \in A$
4. If it were also the case that, for all $k \not \in A$, $Q$ proves $\lnot h(k)$, then $A$ would be recursive. The decision procedure would be: given $k$, search for a proof in $Q$ of $h(k)$ or $\lnot h(k)$. Then $k \in A$ or $k \not \in A$, accordingly, from (3).
5. Thus there is some true $\forall$-rudimentary sentence, which is of the form $\lnot h(k)$ for some $k$, which $Q$ does not prove.

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is definable by a $\exists$-rudimentary formula? I'm not sure how you're making this deduction since $A$ is semirecursive, but not recursive.  Explanation might help - this is in reference to (1) at the bottom of your post.

Comment: @afedder: this is either the definition of a semirecursive set, or a standard theorem, depending on the conventions each author follows. The semirecursive sets are exactly the $\Sigma^0_1$ sets.

Comment: I see the leap for a recursive set, but not for a semirecursive set...the standard theorem would be for a recursive set, not for a semirecursive set.

Comment: We have that $n$ is in the $e$th r.e. set if and only if $(\exists s) [T(e,n,s) = 0]$. Here $T$ is Kleene's $T$ predicate which can be expressed by a $\Sigma^0_1$ formula. These are the standard results I was referring to.

Comment: What is Kleene's $T$ predicate? I am not familiar with this, if you could explain, it would be helpful. I am familiar with Kleene's Theorem, which says that if a set and its complement are both semirecursive, then the set (and hence also its complement) is recursive.  I'm also not very familiar with the $\Sigma_{1}^{0}$ notation, although I've seen it used very often.  Is this just an existential formula of the form $\exists xF(x)$ for some formula $F(x)$, or is this something to do with the property of being primitive recursive/recursive?

Comment: @CarlMummert If (1.) is true, why does Boolos' textbook (where the OP originates) make a distinction between definability and semidefinability.  In particular, Boolos writes "every semirecursive set is (positively) semidefinable in $\mathbf{Q}$," seeming to imply that such sets are *not* always definable in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Carl Mummert, I think I can simplify my question.  Using the second items of both of the OP's two facts above, we have: (1) every recursive relation (e.g., sets) is definable in Q, and (2) every set definable in Q is recursive.  Taken together, doesn't that mean that no strictly-semirecursive set is definable in Q? (@CarlMummert )

Comment: @Doubt In Carl's (1), "Definable" means arithmetically definable, which is not at all  the same thing as "definable in $Q$".

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Okay, this is helpful.  So, if I'm understanding correctly, every set that is arithmetically definable is definable in $\mathbf{Q}$, but not vice versa.

Comment: @Doubt Other way around. Definable in Q is much stronger. It implies (actually is equivalent to) recursive, whereas non-recursive sets (even non-semi-recursive sets) can be arithmetically definable.

Comment: @Doubt The theory of $\mathbb N$ (i.e. all true first order statements about $\mathbb N$) is much stronger than Q, which can't even prove $\forall x, y (x+y=y+x).$ So it can define way more sets. Despite its weakness even amongst axiomatizable theories, $Q$ can define all recursive sets, which is the most any consistent axiomatizable theory could possibly define. (So, e.g. the much stronger PA, for all its extra strength, can't define any new sets.) The theory of $\mathbb N$ is of course not axiomatizable, and as such, it can define a much larger range of sets than just the recursive ones.