# Showing that all semirecursive sets are semidefinable

Tags: logic, model-theory

I'm working on this problem from Boolos' *Computability and Logic*:

> A set $P$ is (positively) semidefinable in a theory $T$ by a formula $\phi(x)$ if for every $n$, $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ is a theorem of $T$ if and only if $n$ is in $P$.  Show that every semirecursive set is (positively) semidefinable in $\mathbf{Q}$ and any $\omega$-consistent extension of $\mathbf{Q}$.

$\mathbf{Q}$ is Boolos' version of Robinson arithmetic.

My intended proof is something like this: let $P$ be a a semirecursive set.  Then there is a recursive relation $R$ such that $P(x)$ iff $\exists y\,R(x,y)$.  Now $R$ is definable in $\mathbf{Q}$ by an $\exists$-rudimentary formula $\psi(x,y)$, and $\exists y\,\psi(x,y)$ is arithmetically equivalent to a $\exists$-rudimentary formula $\phi(x)$.

Does this correctly connect the dots from $P(n)$ to $\phi(\mathbf{n})$, and back again?  If so, where does $\omega$-consistency enter in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semirecursive set $P$ is one such that there is a Turing machine $T$ that accepts on input $n$ if and only if $n\in P.$ The expression “T accepts on input $n$” is a $\Sigma_1$ (what the book calls “$\exists$-rudimentary”) formula $\varphi(n)$. The theory about $Q$ and recursive functions implies $Q$ proves every true $\Sigma_1$ sentence, so if $n\in P,$ then $Q\vdash \varphi(\mathbf n).$

Where $\omega$-consistency comes in is in showing the other direction. If $n\notin P$ and nonetheless $T\vdash \varphi(\mathbf n),$ then $T$ proves a false $\Sigma_1$ sentence, i.e. it proves there exists a number satisfying a $\Delta_0$ property when in fact non exists. (I don’t recall the book’s jargon for $\Delta_0$... it’s the one where all quantifiers are bounded.) Since $T$ extends $Q$, it can disprove every false $\Delta_0$ sentence. So $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks spaceisdarkgreen.  Can you take a look at my post, to see if I properly filled in the details from what you outlined here?

Comment: Analogously to the difference between recursive and semirecursive, “definable” will has an additional clause that $\lnot \phi(\mathbf n)$ is a theorem iff $n\notin P.$ “Arithmetically definable” means definable in this sense, in the case where the theory is $Th(\mathbb N).$ Notice since this theory is complete, semidefinable implies definable so there is no distinction (so there’s no reason to talk about “arithmetically semidefinable”), whereas the distinction is important for incomplete theories.

Comment: (That was an answer to the question you asked in the comments but have since deleted, not a comment on your answer, which I will look at.)

Comment: Great answer, and your comment here is extremely helpful (this was exactly my question about "arithmetical semidefinability").

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be a semirecursive one-place relation.  By definition, $P(x)\leftrightarrow \exists x R(x,y)$ for some recursive relation $R$.  Now every recursive relation is definable in $\mathbf{Q}$ by an $\exists$-rudimentary formula (Boolos: Theorem 16.16).  Since $\exists$-rudimentary formulas are preserved under unbounded existential quantification (Boolos: Lemma 16.9), $P$ is arithmetically definable by an $\exists$-rudimentary formula $\phi(x)$.  That is, $P(n)$ iff $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ is true in the standard interpretation of arithmetic.  Since an $\exists$-rudimentary sentence $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ is true (in the standard interpretation of arithmetic) iff it is a theorem of $\mathbf{Q}$, we have $\mathbf{Q}\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ iff $P(n)$, so $P$ is semidefinable in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Now we must expand this result to a theory $T$ which is an extension of $\mathbf{Q}$.  We must show that $T\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ iff $P(n)$.

1. If $P(n)$ is true, then $\mathbf{Q}\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$, so
   $T\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ since $T$ extends $\mathbf{Q}$.
2. If $T\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ and $\neg P(n)$, then
   $\mathbf{Q}\not\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ since
   $\mathbf{Q}\vdash\phi(\mathbf{n})$ iff P(n).  But since $\mathbf{Q}$
   proves all correct $\exists$-rudimentary sentences, and
   $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ is $\exists$-rudimentary, $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ must
   be false in the standard interpretation.  Let $\psi(x,y)$ be a
   rudimentary formula such that $\phi(x)\leftrightarrow\exists
   y\,\psi(x,y)$.  Since $\phi(\mathbf{n})$ is false, and since 
   $\psi(x,y)$ is rudimentary, $\mathbf{Q}\vdash\neg\psi(\mathbf{n},\mathbf{m})$ for all $m$, and
   hence $T\vdash\neg\psi(\mathbf{n},\mathbf{m})$ for all $m$.  Thus since $T\vdash\neg\psi(\mathbf{n},\mathbf{m})$ for all $m$ and yet $T\vdash\exists y\,\psi(\mathbf{n},y)$, $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

Now 1. and 2., taken together, make $P$ semidefinable in $T$.

Comment: My two questions are: (1) did I need to assume $\mathbf{Q}\vdash\neg\phi(\mathbf{n})$ (is this the same as assuming $\mathbf{Q}$ is consistent)? (2) what more would be needed to show that $P$ is not only semidefinable, but *definable*?

Comment: (1) No, $\phi(\mathbb n)$ is false because $\phi$ defines $P$. Then $\lnot \psi(m,n)$ is true for all $m$ and you can just use the fact that $Q$ proves all correct rudimentary sentences to get $T\vdash\lnot \psi(m,n).$ You cannot assume $T$ proves $\lnot\phi$ just because it does not prove $\phi.$ That is a completeness assumption, not consistency. The reason it works for $\psi(m,n)$ is since the negation of a rudimentary sentence is rudimentary, the fact that $Q$ proves all true rudimentary sentences means it is complete with respect to rudimentary sentences.

Comment: (2) Assuming $P$ is fully recursive will imply $Q$ fully defines it. I don’t think it’s immediately obvious from what’s been discussed here (there are clearly two formulas that work for the positive and negative side, but it requires some thought how to get a single formula or to prove the necessary equivalences in $Q$). I don’t have your book in front of me but it certainly at least proves that Q represents all recursive functions. Then consider the indicator function

Comment: Thanks spaceisdarkgreen -- I made the corresponding correction to the second-to-last sentence of part 2; please see if you agree.

Comment: Also, it seems the key point, with regards to your comment on (1), is that the negation of rudimentary sentences are rudimentary, but the negation of $\exists$-rudimentary sentences are *not* $\exists$-rudimentary.

Comment: Yes, that looks right. And yes, that’s very important. The negation of a $\exists$-rudimentary might be called a $\forall$-rudimentary (or $\Pi_1$ in the more common jargon). And $Q$ most certainly does not prove all true $\Pi_1$ sentences, in fact the Godel sentence for $Q$ is a true $\Pi_1$ sentence. Recall the argument why if a theory proves all true rudimentary sentences, then it proves all true $\exists$-rudimentary sentences and observe that the argument will not work if you replace $\exists$ with $\forall$ or “proves all true” with “refutes all false.”

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Now I am conflicted, after to returning to the question here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750948/textbfq-fails-to-prove-some-correct-forall-rudimentary-sentence).  Don't the OP's two "facts" labeled "2.", taken together, mean that a set is definable in $\mathbf{Q}$ *if and only if* it is recursive?  I can't find anything wrong with his facts, however.

Comment: Yes, "only if" is true too. What is the conflict with what was discussed here?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Well, here we have a semirecursive set $P$.  So doesn't this biconditional mean, in fact, that $P$ is actually recursive?  If so, the whole *semi*definability concept would be moot.

Comment: No, why would it mean that? The biconditional says "recursive if and only if definable in Q". The theorem in the problem says that "semirecursive -> semidefinable in Q" (and in fact, the converse of this one holds as well). How would that mean "semirecursive -> recursive"? That would only follow if semidefinable implied definable, but it doesn't.